# Why is FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh() is never called?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Maybe I am doing a wrong step. I have 3 activities:

- Launcher
- Login
- MainActivity

In the `onCreate` of my MainActivity, I am calling the service:

```
   void iniciarServicioSendTokenFCM(){

        servicioFCM= new Intent(this, IDService.class);
        startService(servicioFCM);

    }
```

And this is executed, because it gets to enter in `onCreate` of Service but `onTokenRefresh()` is never executed.

I have done these [steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites) too. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app but it didn't work.

```
public class IDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private ConnectionStatusSync ConnSync;//= new ConnectionStatusSync(this);
    private DispositivoSync Sync;
    private Integer dispositivoId;
    private PreferenceUtil preferenceUtil ;
    private String tokenDispositivo;
    private DispositivoSync.OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;
    public IDService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Listener();
        ConnSync = new ConnectionStatusSync(this);
        Sync = new DispositivoSync(this);
        preferenceUtil= new PreferenceUtil(this);

        dispositivoId=preferenceUtil.getInt(getString(R.string.dispositivoID),0,null);
        dispositivoId=(dispositivoId==0?null:dispositivoId);
        tokenDispositivo= new IDUtil(this).getId();


    }

    private  void Listener(){
        listener = new DispositivoSync.OnFragmentInteractionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFinished(boolean terminoBien, int dispositivoID) {
                if(terminoBien){
                    preferenceUtil.savePreference(getString(R.string.dispositivoID),dispositivoID,null);

                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        preferenceUtil.savePreference(getString(R.string.TokenFCM),refreshedToken,null);
        //Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        if(validaciones())
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private  boolean validaciones(){

        return  dispositivoId!=null && MainActivity.mOperador!=null;
    }

    private  void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token){



        final Thread registrar = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
Sync.EnviarDispositivo(MainActivity.mOperador.getOperadorIdServidor(),dispositivoId,token,tokenDispositivo,listener );
            }
        });

        Thread hilo  = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Command commandNull= new Command() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute() {

                    }
                };

               ConnSync.CheckConnection(registrar,commandNull);

            }
        });

        hilo.start();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging, the client immediately starts generating the token when the app starts.

Most likely the initial token has already been generated by the time you start listening for `onTokenRefresh()`. So you'll want to also immediately request and store the token in your `iniciarServicioSendTokenFCM` method:

```
sendRegistrationToServer(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
```

I don't think it is very useful to store the token in shared preferences by the way, given that it is readily accessible from `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`.